# Access application and folders located in host from the guest machine

Tags: virtualbox, samba, netbeans

I'm totally new to use virtual box and Ubuntu and I have question regarding access files and application that installed in the host machine. My host machine OS  is Windows 7 and the guest machine is Ubuntu. 
I have installed XAMPP and need use it to develop a web application. my question are:

- how can I copy my application folder to guest xampp/htdocs?
- how can I access netbeans that installed in my windows host from my Ubuntu guest?
- how to share folder? I added a shared folder by changing setting of virtual machine, but when I tried to access it in the guest i couldn't find the folder that I shared in media folder.

please can anyone help me?? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Folders shared from settings will show up on desktop if you install the Guest Tools. (while in machine, go to devices menu and click Install Guest addions. Execute the install bash script from the dvd that mounts.

That shared folders are accessible also via "browse network" in the sidebar of Nautilus (the file manager of Ubuntu).

Any files can be copied using the shared folders (place them in the folder from the guest and take them from the host or vice-versa).

About netbeans, just go to Ubuntu Software Center and download it. You can't use the Windows one.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answering. 
- I haven't install Guest Tool. can you please tell me how to install it, as I mentioned I am totally new to use the virtual box and Ubuntu.
- For net beans, is that means that I can't use any tool that installed in host machine? Because I need to access many tools and I do not have enough space to install them in my guest machine.

Thanks again for response.
Regards,
Rose

Comment: @Rose Hi rose, I am currently on my mobile phone and can't explain how to install the guest add-ons. Will come up later at evening. About the tools, you can not use any of the windows one on Linux (ubuntu) , except for Java tools (.jar executables). But tools for ubuntu (IDEs, gfx processing etc) are usually lightweight and can be downloaded from Ubuntu Software Center (it's in the sidebar --launcher-- of Unity interface).